# get some metadata about a video file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, video

I am currently working on a rails application in which the user upload a video file on the server, after what I send it to S3 where it's encoded by another service.

The thing is that before uploading it to S3 I need to know the quality of this file, the resolution, the bitrate, ...

I saw that the rvideo gem can do that but I'd like to avoid having to install ffmpeg on my rails server.

So my question is do you see a way to do that without much dependency ?

Thanks,

**UPDATE:** I also saw 2 gems wrapping the MediaInfo CLI but same problem I'd like to avoid installing  MediaInfo CLI  on my rails servers

Comment: It might be helpful to specify which types of video files you want to handle.

Comment: any video format ... flv, avi, mpeg, ...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the inspect command available in unix. I know paperclip uses it with their photo processing.